# Symfony2 assign property throws parse error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
*/
protected $createdAt = new DateTime();
```

This is the critical part of my entity definition where the parser raises an error:

```
Parse error: parse error in ...
```

when I execute

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Whats wrong about this? The createdAt field should be assigned when the entity is first created. I am on symfony2.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the assignment to the property in the constructor. You can't assign a new object in that way.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}
```